# Checkbox Action Event

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, checkbox

Looking for some help with checkbox(switch type) that I have put in PHP.
These checkbox are created dynamically with data received from a MySQL Database.
The checkbox is loaded on the page depending on the condition of the checkbox placed on the database.

Now, I need help to build a code that perform some action like writing back into another database table everytime this checkbox is actioned; i.e. its inital state can be `:checked` or left blank(unchecked) and each of these checkbox have an ID or value on them from database. But any action that takes place either from blank to `:checked` or from `:checked` to blank, it needs to trigger an action for that particular actioned checkbox only.

Would need help on this as PHP please.

My Code Looks like this for a checkbox:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' class='input-swtoggle' name='switch-box' ";
$lightStatus = $row->light_status;
if ($lightStatus == "1") {
   echo "checked>";
}
else{
   echo ">";
}
```

PS: I did try alot Googling and on Stackoverflow, but none of them are helping for the above condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind click event to the checkbox using `.on()`

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click',"input:checkbox.input-swtoggle",function() {
     alert($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

Comment: This is functional, but not capturing the unchecked state for me. But I am not sure where I can insert the Logic here.
does this require to be inside a form or can i have it outside as well?
Sorry, but am new to PHP.

Comment: this is jQuery, can be anywhere in html but recommended to have it in `<head>`. This code - `$(this).is(':checked')`  will give you the status of checkbox whether it is checked or blank.

Comment: @Thank you Bhushan, so ideally are we looking at it giving a Boolean result in return? as in, it say a YES or NO depending on the :checked state of the checkbox? and then we write the logic depending on YES and a NO?

Comment: `$(this).is(':checked')` will return true if checked and false for unchecked checkbox. You can put your logic accordingly.

Comment: I did the logic using the if-else for the boolean i get out of this.
but any action gives me output of false.
here's the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fqkq4hqy/1/
Please guide me as to where am making the mistake.

Comment: don't compare boolean value with `=="true"`, just put boolean directly in if condition, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fqkq4hqy/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// HTML code
$checkced = ($row->light_status == '1') ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
echo '<input type="checkbox" class="input-swtoggle" name="switchbox[]"' . $checkced . '/>';
// Code after form posted:
if (! empty($_POST['switchbox'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['switchbox'] as $switch) {
        // Apply your logic here.
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: the HTML code creation is neat and that help alot.
But the my code is not inside a form. Do you say it is good that I place it inside a form and then perform this, ideally I do not want the page to redirect anywhere, but stay on this page showing the checkbox.

Comment: You can redirect it or put it on same page using the condition if (isset($_POST)) { // Your posted code} else {// Your HTML Form}

Comment: Ok, understood. Will try it now and confirm.